# Gulp 4.0 Ignore watch not working

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have the following code:

```
 gulp.task('watch:Feature', function() {
        gulp.watch(['./js/Feature/**/*.ts', '!./js/Feature/.gulp-tsc-tmp*.ts'], function () { console.log("Test"); });
    });
```

I've substituted my typescript build task for `console.log("Test")` and am copying a file with the name: `.gulp-tsc-tmp-1151023-9976-e1a1h3.ts` into the `Feature` directory, which causes "Test" to be output to the console.

I've tried all sorts of exclude patterns including specifying the exact filename I'm copying into the directory, none of which seem to work.

What would be the correct way of ignoring files with a particular prefix?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this a few weeks back and was informed that feature was removed, I didn't have time to establish if that was true but certainly none of my previously working 'ignores' were working on updated release.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to ignore files in a watch in gulp 4 is this:

```
gulp.watch('js/Feature/**/*.ts', {
    ignored: 'js/Feature/.gulp-tsc-tmp*.ts'
}, function () {
    console.log('Test');
});
```

See [the documentation](https://gulpjs.org/API.html#opts).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too, and solved it by removing "./" from the beginning of my paths:

```
gulp.task('watch:Feature', function() {
    gulp.watch(['js/Feature/**/*.ts', '!js/Feature/.gulp-tsc-tmp*.ts'], function () { console.log("Test"); });
});
```